# Is there any necessary to use pool in async redis client

Tags: asynchronous, redis, hiredis

I use async redis api(hiredis) in my project with one connection, because of non-blocking io, so I think one connection is enough for me, but I want to figure out whether the sequence of commands will be executed first-in-first-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation seems to suggest it is first in first out.
https://github.com/redis/hiredis

> In an asynchronous context, commands are automatically pipelined due
>   to the nature of an event loop

Yes you don't need a pool. One connection should be sufficient.